# When a transfer is on-going on Send Anywhere is there any way to see what code (6-digit number) was used?

Tags: file-sharing

When a transfer is on-going on https://send-anywhere.com/ is there any way to see what code (6-digit number) was used to initiate the transfer from the downloader side?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

My name is Suhyuk, from the Send Anywhere team.
The 6-digit code expires once it is used, so it doesn't show after the transfer begins. If the code was a mix of alphabets and digits—in case of 24hr saved files—, then the sending device should have it on the history menu of the Send Anywhere app.